# Trouble referencing labels with Active Reports

Tags: c#, activereports, myob

Ok, so to start off, this is my first time working with C#, and the top it off I am attempting to work with it in a report editor for MYOBs AEPM software, which doesn't exactly give me a lot of info or flexibility. What I have been able to work out is that it uses some version of Data Dynamics Active Reports, but not sure which one. I also cannot seem to figure out what naming they have used for much of the report. Anyway, back to the main issue.

I am needing to add some calculations to the report that the visual editor wont allow me to do(it is restricted to Count, Sum, Min, Max, Avg, Var, so not really helpful). Now the calculations are pretty simple(One is a total x .7, and the other being the result of the first  x 74 but this value might be changed in the future). Figured the best way would be to just have 2 text boxes with a value in each of them of "0", and then just once the main report is pretty much done run the calculations and replace the values of the two text boxes. So I made the text boxes in the appropriate section and labelled them CalcTotal1 and CalcTotal2.

Now in the editor it allows me to select the object and an event to trigger it, so selected ReportFooter as the object and AfterPrint as the event. I then just put in a line to chance the CalcTotal1 value and tried to generate the report resulting in the following error:

> Error Message: Report Script Compile Error on line 8 Error = The name 'CalcTotal1' does not exist in the current context

```
public void ReportFooter_AfterPrint()
{
    CalcTotal1.Text = "Hello";
}
```

I have tried looking at the documentation for Active Reports but I am not having much luck, so any ideas would be incredibly welcome.

Comment: Here's the hint on making custom totals. Add custom data field, feed it with custom data and bind total fields to that data field. See http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/CalculatedFieldsSample.html for example.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MYOB AE PM feature referred to is called Smart Reports. 
I was able to replicate the error and consequently resolved the problem by using the following syntax:

```
((TextBox)rpt.Sections["Detail"].Controls["TextBox2"]).Text= "$2000.00";
```

eg:

```
public void Detail_AfterPrint()
{
((TextBox)rpt.Sections["Detail"].Controls["TextBox2"]).Text= "$2000.00";

}
```

Comment: I'm not in the office for a couple of days so wont be able able to check that until I get back, but if that did work on your end, it should work on ours. If short, thank you so very very much.

Comment: Ok, I am not getting any exceptions being thrown, but the value of the text box(TextBox2) isn't being changed. The name of the text box is TextBox2, it is in the ReportHeader section(have changed both the function an the sections part of the code to represent that). Besides that, the code is exactly the same as what you posted, and all settings of the textbox are default.

Comment: Sorry for another comment. ALL SOLVED! Had to change the function to be _Format() instead of _AfterPrint(). That fixed it and it is now working wonderfully! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

just add "this" word in the code like

```
this.CalcTotal1.Test = "Hello";
```

http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR8Help/AR8_HelpOnlineEN/Scripts.html provides some more tips.

Comment: Nah, that doesn't work, gives me "Does not contain a definition for CalcTotal1"

Comment: can you make sure that a textbox control named "CalcTotal1" exists in report footer section of the report?  Also, the property is Text, not Test.  Can you attach the report here or email it to rajnish.sinha@grapecity.com?

Comment: It did exist. Found code that doesn't throw any exceptions(Andrew Smith's answer below), but it doesn't appear to be changing the text box text value, and yes all the variables are set correctly.

Comment: And solution has been found.